# How to create dynamically named objects based on array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have an array of string values which represent some events I want to subscribe to:

```
[M123, M255,M345, M938...] //localMatchStore - could be of any length
```

I want to create a new socket.io connection for each value in the array with a dynamic name e.g socket_M123, socket_M255, socket_M345, socket_M938.

I then need to reference each new socket connection so that I can subscribe to the event name in my array. I need a distinct socket connection for each event.

```
var localMatchStore= [];
for (var i in data.matches) {
    if (data.matches.hasOwnProperty(i)) localMatchStore.push(data.matches[i]);
}
```

How do I create a new object with a dynamic name for each array entry?

I want to end of with a number of socket connections e.g.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://'+server+':'+port+'');
socket1.emit('subscribe', { myid: 'M123'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like this?

```
myConnectionArray["socket_"+eventName] = //new socket.io connection
```

Everything in javascript is an associative array.